# Why is median blur not working? - OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, types

I have a function to add gaussian noise to an image read by OpenCV with `imread` that returns an image (matrix).

I am trying to use median blur on that image but terminal returns this error:

```
median = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:/a/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/median_blur.simd.hpp:870: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'cv::opt_AVX2::medianBlur'
```

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def GaussianNoise(image):

    row,col,ch= image.shape

    mean = -10
    var = 200
    sigma = var**0.5

    gauss = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col,ch))
    gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch)
    gaussImage = image + gauss

    return gaussImage

def ApplyFilters(image):

    median = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)

    return  median

def CleanImage():
    image = cv2.imread("SampleImages/Sample1.png")

    noiseImage = GaussianNoise(image)
    cleanedImage = ApplyFilters(noiseImage)

    cv2.imshow("Clean image", cleanedImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CleanImage()
```

I don't understand why it says `error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)` if it seems to be both valid images (matrixes) and `ksize` seems to be correct too.

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** image info is `col = 1024` `row = 1024` `ch = 3` `dtype = uint8`

Comment: What is the shape and dtype of your "image" image? Are they valid for medianBlur()?  Check the documentation

Comment: As OpenCV documentation states "src = input 1-, 3-, or 4-channel image; when ksize is 3 or 5, the image depth should be CV_8U". My image has 3 channels and it is unit8, so still seems valid... or that's what I think

Comment: Forget that, I figured what you mean. I did the incorrect dtype check, I made it on the source image, not the resultant from GaussianNoise( ). dtype was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution fmw42 provided.

My mistake was assuming that my image was always `uint8`, beacuse on this lines:

```
gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch)
gaussImage = image + gauss
```

`gauss` is `float64`, so when `image` and `gauss` are added, the result turns into `float64` too.

I read on documentation that `medianBlur()` accepts only `uint8`, `uint16` and `float32`.

So, in order to solve this I had to turn `gauss` to `uint8` before its addition (the resultant addition can be turned into `uint8` too insted), like this:

```
gauss = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col,ch))
gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch).astype("uint8")
gaussImage = image + gauss
```

My final code will be this one:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def GaussianNoise(image):

    row,col,ch= image.shape

    mean = -10
    var = 200
    sigma = var**0.5

    gauss = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col,ch))
    gauss = gauss.reshape(row,col,ch).astype("uint8")
    gaussImage = image + gauss

    return gaussImage

def ApplyFilters(image):

    median = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)

    return  median

def CleanImage():
    image = cv2.imread("SampleImages/Sample1.png")

    noiseImage = GaussianNoise(image)
    cleanedImage = ApplyFilters(noiseImage)

    cv2.imshow("Clean image", cleanedImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CleanImage()
```